# URL Not Loading in Webview (redirection)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview, redirect

When I am trying to load this `http://feeds.feedblitz.com/~/33712999/0/technicallypersonal~Top-Biking-Apps-for-Android-and-iOS-iPhoneiPad/` kind of urls in an UIWebView and they do not load (I believe it's because of the redirection)

What can I do to make them work?

Comment: can you post the code..?? It will help you get some real answers.

Comment: Doing a simple `[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feeds.feedblitz.com/~/33712999/0/technicallypersonal~Top-Biking-Apps-for-Android-and-iOS-iPhoneiPad/"]]];` seems to work fine. What is not working for you?

Comment: @Rob It do not loads for me, it just shows a blank page (White Page)

Comment: @RajanBalana works fine for me. See my answer with code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're getting a blank page, but it works fine for me. I have a `UIWebView` hooked up to an `IBOutlet` named `webview`, and then I have a `viewDidLoad` that does:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feeds.feedblitz.com/~/33712999/0/technicallypersonal~Top-Biking-Apps-for-Android-and-iOS-iPhoneiPad/"]]];
}
```

I've done that and it works fine. So, you say that you just get a blank page, so I wonder if your `IBOutlet` is working. Try just a simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.webview loadHTMLString:@"<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
}
```

If that works, then the problem is loading from the web, in which case I'd suggest trying different URLs with the `loadRequest` method, to see if it's all URLs, or just your particular URL. If the `loadHTMLString` doesn't work, then it's got to be something simple like your `IBOutlet` is not set up correctly, or something like that.